# How do I avoid installing .NET assemblies in the GAC on our build server?

Tags: .net

We're using Windows Identity Foundation in some of our applications. On the developer machines, this installs various bits into the GAC.

I'd rather not do this on our build agents.

In general, how do I pull .NET assemblies from the GAC so that I can reference them in our builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you put "copy local", in order to avoid deploy problems. (right click on the reference, properties, copy local, true).

Hope it helps

Comment: So I'd do this as a one-off in order to get the files out of the GAC, and then copy them to our '3rdParty' folder, and then edit the references, yes?

Comment: If you do this, your dependecies will be copied on the destination bin directory. Then, there is no need to install on the destination server's gac. Your app will make references to the dlls on your bin folder.

Comment: "build server" => not my machine, not the destination machine.

Comment: If you put the "copy to local" option, you will see the dependencies in your bin folder (dlls). If you have a build server compiling that project, there is no need to configure gac. If you publish your project, the packaga will contain the dependencies, then you can install that app to any pc/server with any gac installation.

Comment: In this specific case, WIF is now available as a NuGet package, so that particular problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

In your references, click each of the Dlls in question and set their "Copy Local" property to True. This should mean that when you build they get copied into the bin folder of the application.